# MySQL Schema DBAdmins can you please look this over?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

Database Schemas are not my strong point however I'm making a Recipe Schema and would like some input from experts on this before I move forward with my code.

InnoDB with relations.

Tabels `Recipe_Steps` and `Recipe_Step_Ingredients` have relations setup for `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` and `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

[image]

Ok I rearranged things a bit, I think I made it more simple without loosing any functionality. Usually recipes list the ingredients and the instructions separate so I don't think I need the steps to be linked to the ingredients.

What do you guys think?

[image]

Comment: In `Recipe_Steps` you use the PK also to cover the sequence of steps - this might give you trouble on inserting a step

Comment: So would you recommend I use something else as a PK for RecipeSteps? How would I handle the MANY to MANY relationship with Recipe_Step_Ingredients and Ingredients?

Comment: Leave the relationship on the PK - this is where it belongs (You might want to call it `id` to be consistent with the rest), but you might think about an additional field like `step_order int not null` and fill it with 1..n for a recipe

Comment: Ok, I changed a few things do you mind looking it over? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I prefer the 1st over the 2nd design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One suggestion is that Recepie steps table is not connected with recepie ingredients.... you might want to do that since different ingredients are used in different steps .

Comment: Yes I did that once I realized that both Epicurious and AllRecipes separate the instructions and the ingredients. Example: http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Dark-Chocolate-Truffles/Detail.aspx?src=rotd